# java : Loop through two ArrayLists without ListIterators using abstract data types

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, abstract-data-type

First, I'm not sure if I conveyed the correct problem in the title of this question, and if so, my apologies.

My problem is this - I'm using a list ADT to simulate a selection game. The idea is a group of children sit in a circle and sing a rhyme. Each child says one word of the rhyme until the rhyme is completed. The last person to say the rhyme is out of the game. The rhyme is then started over from the next child. The last child left is the winner.

The application will read the number of players in the game and the rhyme from the keyboard. Two lists will be created, one for the players, and one for the rhyme. The arraylists uses an interface for the methods.

I'm in the process of writing the code to loop through both lists, at least once (I think), in order to run through the players alongside the rhyme, to find who will be eliminated. Once that person is eliminated, the player list will shrink by one (the rhyme list stays the same), and the loop will start over again.

This is the doRhyme() method.

My problem so far is when I run what I have in the code, my return is this:

```
Please enter the number of players
(It should be an integer value greater than or equal to 2):5
The players list is:   1  2  3  4  5
Please enter a rhyme:
One Two Three Four Five
Player 1: One
Player 2: Two
Player 5: Three
Player null: Four
Player null: Five
Rhyme performance error!
The players list is:   5

The winner is: 5
```

I used One Two Three Four Five as the rhyme just to test the code out. I hope that doesn't confuse anyone.

The output code SHOULD look like this:

```
Please enter the number of players
(It should be an integer value greater than or equal to 2):5
The players list is:   1  2  3  4  5
Please enter a rhyme: One Two Three Four Five
Player 1: One
Player 2: Two
Player 3: Three
Player 4: Four
Player 5: Five
Removing player 5
The players list is:   1  2  3  4

Player 1: One
Player 2: Two
Player 3: Three
Player 4: Four
Player 1: Five
Removing player 1
The players list is:   2  3  4

and so on until only one player is left....
```

Included here is the code so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will be continuing to figure out the correct code in the meantime.

```
    public class RhymeGame
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            ListInterface<Integer> players = null;
            ListInterface<String> rhyme = null;

            int max;
            int position = 1;

            max = getInt();
            players = new AList<Integer>();

            for(int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
            {
                players.add(i);
            }

            System.out.println("The players list is: " + players);

            rhyme = getRhyme();

            while(players.getLength() > 1)
            {
                position = doRhyme(players, rhyme, position);

                System.out.println("The players list is: " + players);
                System.out.println();  
            }

            System.out.println("The winner is: " + players.getEntry(1));

        }//end of main

        //Requires user to input the number of players.
        private static int getInt()
        {
            Scanner input;
            int result = 10;        //default value is 10

            try
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter the number of players\n(It should be an integer value greater than or equal to 2):");
                input = new Scanner(System.in);
                result = input.nextInt();
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Could not convert input to an integer");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Will use 10 as the default value");
            }        
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("There was an error with System.in");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Will use 10 as the default value");
            }

            return result;

        }//end of getInt

        //Requires user to input a rhyme
        //(does not necessarily have to rhyme)
        private static ListInterface<String> getRhyme()
        {
            Scanner input;
            Scanner rhymeWords;
            String inString;

            ListInterface<String> rhyme = new AList<String>();

            try
            {
                input = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Please enter a rhyme:");

                inString = input.nextLine().trim();
                rhymeWords = new Scanner(inString);

                while(rhymeWords.hasNext())
                {
                    rhyme.add(rhymeWords.next());
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Input error!");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                getRhyme();
            }

            //At least one word in the rhyme
            if(rhyme.getLength() < 1)
            {
                System.out.println("You must enter at least one word in the rhyme");
                getRhyme();
            }

            return (ListInterface<String>)rhyme;

        }//end of getRhyme

        //Loops through the rhyme with the players in the list, 
        //removing the selected player at the end of the rhyme.
        //
        //players = the list holding the players
        //rhyme = the list holding the words of the rhyme
        //startAt = a position to start the rhyme at
        //
        //the position of the player eliminated will be returned.
        public static int doRhyme(ListInterface<Integer> players, ListInterface<String> rhyme, int startAt)
        {   
            int numPlayers;

            try
            {
                numPlayers = players.getLength();

                while(numPlayers > 2)
                {
                    for(startAt = 1; startAt < players.getLength(); startAt++)
                    {
                        for(startAt = 1; startAt < rhyme.getLength() + 1; startAt++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Player " + players.getEntry(startAt) + ": " + rhyme.getEntry(startAt));
                            numPlayers = players.remove(--numPlayers);
                        }                   
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Rhyme performance error!");
            }

            return startAt;

         }//end of doRhyme

    }//end of class
```

The interface for the list is as follows (in case anyone wants to see the methods I have to work with).

```
    /** 
        An interface for the ADT list.
        Entries in the list have positions that begin with 1.
    */
    public interface ListInterface<T>
    {

       /** Adds a new entry to the end of this list.
           Entries currently in the list are unaffected.
           The list's size is increased by 1.
           @param newEntry the object to be added as a new entry */
       public void add(T newEntry);

       /** Adds a new entry at a specified position within this list.
           Entries originally at and above the specified position
           are at the next higher position within the list.
           The list's size is increased by 1.
           @param newPosition  an integer that specifies the desired
                               position of the new entry
           @param newEntry  the object to be added as a new entry
           @return true if the addition is successful, or
                   false if newPosition < 1, or newPosition > getLength() + 1 */
       public boolean add(int newPosition, T newEntry);

       /** Removes the entry at a given position from this list.
           Entries originally at positions higher than the given
           position are at the next lower position within the list,
           and the list's size is decreased by 1.
           @param givenPosition  an integer that indicates the position of
                                 the entry to be removed
           @return a reference to the removed entry or null, if either
                   the list was empty, givenPosition < 1, or
                   givenPosition > getLength() */
       public T remove(int givenPosition);

       /** Removes all entries from this list. */
       public void clear();

       /** Replaces the entry at a given position in this list.
           @param givenPosition  an integer that indicates the position of
                                 the entry to be replaced
           @param newEntry  the object that will replace the entry at the
                            position givenPosition
           @return true if the replacement occurs, or false if either the
                   list is empty, givenPosition < 1, or
                   givenPosition > getLength() */
       public boolean replace(int givenPosition, T newEntry);

       /** Retrieves the entry at a given position in this list.
           @param givenPosition  an integer that indicates the position of
                                 the desired entry
           @return a reference to the indicated entry or null, if either
                   the list is empty, givenPosition < 1, or
                   givenPosition > getLength() */
       public T getEntry(int givenPosition);

       /** Sees whether this list contains a given entry.
           @param anEntry the object that is the desired entry
           @return true if the list contains anEntry, or false if not */
       public boolean contains(T anEntry);

       /** Gets the length of this list.
           @return the integer number of entries currently in the list */
       public int getLength();

       /** Sees whether this list is empty.
           @return true if the list is empty, or false if not */
       public boolean isEmpty();

       /** Retrieves all entries that are in this list in the order in which
           they occur in the list. */
       public T[] toArray();  
    }
```

The definitions for AList are as follows:

```
    /**
       A class that implements the ADT list by using an array.
       The list is unbounded.
     */
    public class AList<T> implements ListInterface<T>
    {
        private T[] list;   // array of list entries
        private int numberOfEntries;
        private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 25;  

        public AList()
        {
            this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);

        }//end of constructor

        public AList(int initialCapacity)
        {
            numberOfEntries = 0;
            T[] tempList = (T[])new Object[initialCapacity];
            list = tempList;

        }//end of constructor

        public void add(T newEntry)
        {
            boolean isSuccessful = true;

            if(!isFull())
            {
                //ensureCapacity();
                list[numberOfEntries] = newEntry;
                numberOfEntries++;
            }
            else
            {
                isSuccessful = false;
            }

        }//end of add

        public boolean add(int newPosition, T newEntry)
        {
            boolean isSuccessful = true;

            if(!isFull() && (newPosition >= 1) && (newPosition <= numberOfEntries + 1)) 
            {   
                ensureCapacity();
                makeRoom(newPosition);              
                list[newPosition - 1] = newEntry;
                numberOfEntries++;
            }
            else
            {
                isSuccessful = false;
            }

            return isSuccessful;

        }//end of add overload

        public T remove(int givenPosition)
        {        
            T result = null; // return value

            if((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= numberOfEntries))                                            
            {   
                assert !isEmpty();

                result = list[givenPosition - 1]; // get entry to be removed

                // move subsequent entries towards entry to be removed, 
                // unless it is last in list
                if(givenPosition < numberOfEntries)
                {
                    removeGap(givenPosition);
                }

                numberOfEntries--;

            } // end if

            return result; // return reference to removed entry, or
            // null if either list is empty or givenPosition
            // is invalid

        }//end of remove

        public void clear()
        {

            for(int index = 0; index < numberOfEntries; index++)
            {
                list[index] = null;
            }

            numberOfEntries = 0;

        }//end of clear

        public boolean replace(int givenPosition, T newEntry)
        {
            boolean isSuccessful = true;

            if(!isFull() && (givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= numberOfEntries)) // test catches empty list
            {
                assert !isEmpty();
                list[givenPosition - 1] = newEntry;
            }
            else
            {
                isSuccessful = false;
            }

            return isSuccessful;

        }//end of replace

        public T getEntry(int givenPosition)
        {
            T result = null; // result to return

            if((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= numberOfEntries))
            {
                assert !isEmpty();
                result = list[givenPosition - 1];
            }

            return result;

        }//end of getEntry

        public boolean contains(T anEntry)
        {
            boolean found = false;

            for(int index = 0; !found && (index < numberOfEntries); index++)
            {
                if(anEntry.equals(list[index]))
                {
                    found = true;
                }
            }

            return found;

        }//end of contains

        public int getLength()
        {
            return numberOfEntries;

        }//end of getLength

        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
            return numberOfEntries == 0;

        }//end of isEmpty

        public boolean isFull()
        {
            return numberOfEntries == list.length;
        }

        public T[] toArray()
        {
            T[] result = (T[])new Object[numberOfEntries];

            for(int index = 0; index < numberOfEntries; index++)
            {
                result[index] = list[index];
            }

            return result;

        }//end of toArray

        public String toString()
        // Returns a nicely formatted string that represents this list.
        {
            String listString = "";

            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++)
            {
                listString = listString + "  " + list[i];
            }

            return listString;

        }//end of toString

        // Doubles the size of the array list if it is full.
        private void ensureCapacity()
        {
            if(numberOfEntries == list.length)
            {
                list = Arrays.copyOf(list, 2 * list.length);
            }

        }//end of ensureCapacity

        //  Makes room for a new entry at newPosition.
        //  Precondition: 1 <= newPosition <= numberOfEntries + 1; 
        //                numberOfEntries is list's length before addition. 

        private void makeRoom(int newPosition)
        {
            assert(newPosition >= 1) && (newPosition <= numberOfEntries + 1);

            int newIndex = newPosition - 1;
            int lastIndex = numberOfEntries - 1;

            // move each entry to next higher index, starting at end of
            // list and continuing until the entry at newIndex is moved
            for(int index = lastIndex; index >= newIndex; index--)
            {
                list[index + 1] = list[index];
            }

        }//end of makeRoom

        // Shifts entries that are beyond the entry to be removed to the 
        // next lower position.
        //  Precondition: 1 <= givenPosition < numberOfEntries;
        //                numberOfEntries is list's length before removal. 

        private void removeGap(int givenPosition)
        {
            assert(givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition < numberOfEntries);

            int removedIndex = givenPosition - 1;
            int lastIndex = numberOfEntries - 1;

            for(int index = removedIndex; index < lastIndex; index++)
            {
                list[index] = list[index + 1];
            }

        }//end of removeGap

    }//end of class
```

Comment: You should use this line in your catch: `System.out.println("Rhyme performance error!\n" + e.getMessage());` or `e.printStackTrace()`. And then add the output here.

Comment: I had it that way originally, but it only adds "null" below the "rhyme performance error!"

Comment: AList is not defined in the code, your code needs refactoring

Comment: Why do you need that try/catch anyway? Let it throw the exception (remove the try/catch). Using `startAt` in both loops seems problematic.

Comment: I think your nested for loop is messing you up. You should think modular arithmetic, and use the size of the larger collection when looping. In other words use one for loop for both collections.

Comment: @firephil - I added the AList.java to my post.

Comment: Please read [help on Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking. Pay attention to [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) concept.

Comment: @naXa - Sorry about that. I'm still new to posting on here. I'll make sure not to make that mistake again.

Comment: @Imposter - there might not be a larger collection if the user picks the same amount of words in the rhyme as there are players.

Comment: you're removing elements from the list while iterating it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:
I see that there are two possible cases:

Case 1:
The size of the rhyme list is larger than or equal to the size of the person list.
Action - remove the last element in the person list.

Case 2:
The size of the person list is larger than the rhyme list.
Action - remove the element in the person list that is at:
 
`index = (person.size() % rhyme.size()) - 1`

Following is a code sample for the application:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    //build lists and populate. Make sure that there are more
    //players than rhymes so we can hit both cases.
    ArrayList<Integer> player = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> rhyme  = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(i < 6){
            rhyme.add(i);
        }
        player.add(i);
    }

    //play the game until we find a winner
    while(player.size() > 1) {

        int indexToRemove;

        //case 1 followed by case 2
        if (rhyme.size() >= player.size()) {
            indexToRemove = player.size() - 1;
        } else {
            indexToRemove = (player.size() % rhyme.size()) - 1;
        }
        System.out.println(player.get(indexToRemove));
        player.remove(indexToRemove);
    }
    System.out.println(player);
}
```

Output:

```
3
2
1
0
9
8
7
6
5
[4]
```

Comment: I think one problem I'm having is that instead of having two integer arraylists, I have one integer arraylist, and one String arraylist. The output should contain both. Here's an example:

    In the circle: [Player 1, Player 2, Player 3, Player 4, Player 5, Player 6] 
    Player 1 <- Eenie, 
    Player 2 <- Meenie, 
    Player 3 <- Mainee, 
    Player 4 <- Mo 
    Player 4 is out!

Comment: I don't think that the the type of the `ArrayList` is what matters. They are indexed data structures regardless. The type of either list does not really matter as long as you are representing your `Players` and `Rhymes` as you want to. You could make `Player` and `Rhyme` types, and still use the properties of the size of each list to decide which player should be removed. Also consider that each time that the game is played there is no iteration. So playing one time takes a constant amount of time as opposed to iterating over a list that will be linear time with respect to the longest list.

Answer (score 0):

Gathering input from user is ommited here (because it doesn't matter for the game to **know** where its input are coming from).

```
private static void runGame(String[] rhyme, List<String> players) {
    System.out.println("Rhyme is " + Arrays.toString(rhyme));
    do {
        System.out.println("The player list is " + players);
        for (int i = 0; i < rhyme.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(players.get(i % players.size()) + ": " + rhyme[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Removing " + players.remove((rhyme.length - 1) % players.size()));
    } while (players.size() > 1);
    System.out.println("The winner is " + players.get(0));
}
```

Output:

```
Rhyme is [one, two, three, four, five]
The player list is [Player 1, Player 2, Player 3, Player 4, Player 5]
Player 1: one
Player 2: two
Player 3: three
Player 4: four
Player 5: five
Removing Player 5
The player list is [Player 1, Player 2, Player 3, Player 4]
Player 1: one
Player 2: two
Player 3: three
Player 4: four
Player 1: five
Removing Player 1
The player list is [Player 2, Player 3, Player 4]
Player 2: one
Player 3: two
Player 4: three
Player 2: four
Player 3: five
Removing Player 3
The player list is [Player 2, Player 4]
Player 2: one
Player 4: two
Player 2: three
Player 4: four
Player 2: five
Removing Player 2
The winner is Player 4
```